# Is there a limit to the number of special lands I can put in my deck, like the Temples?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-manabase

I'm constructing a Deck and I want to make all the mana Temple Cards. More Specifically I want them to be [Temple of Silence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTemple%20of%20Silence%5d), [Temple of Plenty](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTemple%20of%20Plenty%5d), and [Temple of Malady](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTemple%20of%20Malady%5d). Are these mana cards limited to only four per deck like regular cards or can you put an unlimited amount of them in your deck?

Answer (score 30):

All cards are limited to 4 per deck except Basic lands, and [cards that say they bypass this limit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20%5B%22A%20deck%20can%20have%20any%20number%20of%20cards%20named%22%5D) (currently [Relentless Rats](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Relentless%20Rats), [Shadowborn Apostle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shadowborn%20Apostle), [Rat Colony](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rat%20Colony), [Persistent Petitioners](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Persistent%20Petitioners), and [Dragon's Approach](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dragon%27s%20Approach)). In the case of Basic lands, this means that the type line, which is the text between the image and the text box, has to start with the word "Basic". The rule that covers this is [100.2a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/General_rules). This limitation does not apply to limited play.

The cards you mention are not Basic lands, so you can only have 4 of each in your deck. The only basic lands are:

- [Plains](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Plains)
- [Island](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Island)
- [Swamp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Swamp)
- [Mountain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mountain)
- [Forest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Forest)
- [Snow-Covered Plains](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snow-Covered%20Plains)
- [Snow-Covered Island](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snow-Covered%20Island)
- [Snow-Covered Swamp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snow-Covered%20Swamp)
- [Snow-Covered Mountain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snow-Covered%20Mountain)
- [Snow-Covered Forest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snow-Covered%20Forest)
- [Wastes](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wastes)

Comment: I've updated this to mention the general case - there's another example of it too.

Comment: Wait, in limited formats, there is no 4 card of each type rule?

Comment: That is correct. Your deck can have as many of each card that you open/draft.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That's a rule I never knew. But I suppose it would rarely matter; since you aren't at all likely to draft more than 4 of any card that you would actually want more than 4 of.

Comment: I've seen it happen. Some commons get very powerful if you have an army of them.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Maybe I should ask this as a new question, but how will the mana produced by Wastes be any different than the mana produced by Inkmoth Nexus?

Comment: It's not. They're exactly the same. Inkmoth Nexus will be errata'd to have generate the same mana Wastes generates.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess it will make it clearer then because the other symbol will now only mean "any mana" instead of "any mana" in costs and "colorless mana" in effects.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - There's a very tiny difference; the mana generated by Wastes can be used to cast Imperiosaur, whereas the mana generated by Inkmoth Nexus cannot.

Comment: Some cards care about the source of mana, but that does not mean that the mana itself is different.

Comment: @GendoIkari there are some commons that are designed around picking as many as possible in limited [Goblin Gathering](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin+Gathering)

Comment: @GendoIkari I have seen it happen more than once, so having no 4 card limit does indeed matter sometimes, Generally commons particularly when no one else went into the color. I remember one draft in Gatecrash where one guy won because he had 5 Madcap Skills in his deck, the cheap permanent buffs let him aggro over everything.

Answer (score 8):

You can only put four of each Temple in your deck. It's only the basic lands that are exempt from the limit:

> 100.2a In constructed play (a way of playing in which each player creates his or her own deck ahead of time), each deck must contain at least sixty cards. A constructed deck may contain any number of basic land cards and no more than four of any card with a particular English name other than basic land cards.

Comment: There are [ten](http://magiccards.info/query?q=t%3A%22Basic%22&v=olist&s=otype) Basic land cards.

Comment: @ikegami 11 basic land cards.